# We took three rests on our way to here

Tags: countable-nouns

Is "rest" a countable noun? Can we use it as below:

> We took three **rests** on our way to here.

Note: maybe it is better if we use it as verb "we rest three times ...", but it just an example. please suggest better one.

I think  (not sure) it is countable because we use *indefinite article* with it.

> I need to stop for **a** rest. I can't walk any further.

Comment: *We rested every fifty miles. We rested after meals. We rested after brushing our teeth. We rested when we got hot. The **rest** of the time, we drove. -- You sure did rest a lot! How many **rests** did you take??!!*    When **rest** means "remaining portion", it is uncountable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/rest) says that **rest** in this sense can be count or uncountable, so the sentence is grammatically correct, however it doesn't sound very natural.

**rest** is much more frequently used as a verb so, as you suggested, "we rested three times" would sound better. Note that you need to use simple past **rested**.

Better still would be to use **break**, which is mainly used as a noun in this sense, and according to [NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=take%20a%20rest%2C%20take%20a%20break&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctake%20a%20rest%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctake%20a%20break%3B%2Cc0) it is much more widely used than **rest**.

> We took three breaks on our way to here.

Answer (score -1):

Rest can be used as a countable noun.  It may help to think of it as being short for "rest break", which is clearly and obviously countable.